# passing my Class JFrame object into a side function

Tags: java, swing

I have created a side class to help me manage functions that i reuses in all of my GUI JFrames

i am using an undecorated JFrame, and i have added a simple functions to be able to drag it around

```
public class SideFunctions {

static int xMouse, yMouse;

public static void frameDragMouseDragged(JFrame frame, MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getXOnScreen();
    int y = e.getYOnScreen();

    frame.setLocation(x - xMouse, y - yMouse);
}

public static void frameDragMouseClicked(JFrame frame, MouseEvent e) {
    xMouse = e.getX();
    yMouse = e.getY();
}
```

inside my EntranceScreen class which extends JFrame i try to do this

```
    private void createFrameDragLabel() {
    frameDrag = new JLabel();
    frameDrag.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            SideFunctions.frameDragMouseDragged(this, arg0);
        }
    });
    frameDrag.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            SideFunctions.frameDragMouseClicked(this, arg0);
        }
    });
    frameDrag.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 400);
}
```

i want 'this' to refer to the JFrame instance but it is refering to the MouseMotionAdapter / MouseAdapter,
how can i pass the JFrame object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the most inner class you currently are, so the anonymous `MouseAdapter`.
Use `EntranceScreen.this` instead.